# i am trying to work on this piece of code but its not working and flashing error on the line mentioned

Tags: sqlite

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
    try {  
        out.println("<html>");

        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet Existing</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");


        HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
        String id,password;
        id=request.getParameter("t1");
        password=request.getParameter("t2");
        session.setAttribute("t1",id);


        int f=0;
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection c;
        c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:c:/java/project");//ERROR COMES HERE  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        /* PreparedStatement ps;
        ps=c.prepareStatement("select id,password from id where id='tirjss' password='020'");

        String id2,pswrd;
        ResultSet r;
                r=ps.executeQuery();
         if(r.next()==true)
         {*/ response.sendRedirect("existing_user.html");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Which is the line mentioned ? and what is the error ?